# How can I extend back-office(dashboard and tree) in Umbraco 6.x?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I would like to extend back-office(dashboard & tree) in Umbraco 6.x
Please introduce some good references about it or explain it.
I've watched a move about it but it wasn't good special in extending tree!
For example I want a custom tree in back-office  like this:

> ```
>                  CustomeTreeNode
>                  |
>                  |---SubTreeNodeA
>                  |---SubTreeNodeB
> ```

"SubTreeNodeA" & "SubTreeNodeB" can contains sub nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation is not there yet, there are several threads about this in the Umbraco forum, e.g.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/42240-Custom-Tree-in-Umbraco-6

And a reasonable article here:

http://www.theoutfield.net/blog/2012/07/creating-custom-applications-and-trees-in-umbraco-48plus

Comment: Thanks. But these links below didn't work correctly.I should investigate further.                       https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/6.1.2/src/Umbraco.Web/umbraco.presentation/umbraco/Trees/loadContent.cs

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/tree/6.1.2/src/Umbraco.Web/umbraco.presentation/umbraco/Trees